# How to call a asp.net mvc action without changing the url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-core, httpresponse

I have a simple controller with 2 custom actions. From the index view there is a link to the action "MyActionA" with id = 3. Then the matching view is returned.

On the view "MyActionA" there is a link (on a submit form button) to the action "HiddenAction".

The action "HiddenAction" only updates a property on given model. I do not want to change the URL on client browser. But I want to send the updated model to the client.

I tried it with Redirect but it never works.
Has anyone an idea?

Here is the controller code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult MyActionA(int id)
    {
        if (id <= 0) throw new ArgumentException();

        HomeModel model = GetModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult HiddenAction(HomeModel model)
    {
        if (model == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));

        model.MyPropB = 999;

        //HttpContext.Response.Redirect()
        return View(model);
        //return Rewrite("MyAtionA/3");
        //return RedirectToAction(nameof(MyActionA), 3);
        //return View();
    }

    // Helper

    private HomeModel GetModel()
    {
        return new HomeModel();
    }

    public class HomeModel
    {
        public int MyPropA { get; set; }
        public int MyPropB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think you'd need `return RedirectToAction(nameof(MyActionA), new { id: 3 });` in order for the redirect to work...

Comment: That's a good solution, thank you. Do you know how to pass the model at redirect? There is no parameter 'model' on RedirectToAction() like on View().

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use AJAX to post the data back to the server (i.e. make the request client-side via JavaScript). Any other method (such as an HTML form) or a link will cause the URL in the browser to change.

Comment: Thank you. AJAX could be a way. Up to yet we wanted to use the basic components without using JS. I would play a bit with it.